# brew bundle reporting "Error: unknown command: bundle"

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I'm completely puzzled by this one. I have refactored my install scripts to use the new `brew bundle` feature. However, I'm getting "Error: unknown command: bundle"

```
$ which brew
/usr/local/bin/brew

$ brew -v
Homebrew 0.9.5

$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: You have a curlrc file
If you have trouble downloading packages with Homebrew, then maybe this
is the problem? If the following command doesn't work, then try removing
your curlrc:
  curl http://github.com

$ brew update
Already up-to-date.

$ cat ~/.dotfiles/install/brewfile-basic
# Important early installs

install hub # https://hub.github.com
install git-extras # https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras
install bash-completion # http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org

# Cleaning up Brew caches

linkapps
cleanup
prune

$ brew bundle ~/.dotfiles/install/brewfile-basic
Error: Unknown command: bundle

$ brew bundle
Error: Unknown command: bundle
```

In all other ways, `brew` is working.

Any ideas? Is this feature not in the current build?

-- Christopher Allen

Answer (score 4):

According to my question on this topic in the issues section of the homebrew repository, brew bundle has been deprecated.

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/32952

Comment: There's a new official alternative here now though:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-brewdler

Answer (score 1):

In essence, all commands you had in your Brewfile can be used in a bash script.

If you want to have a single file for your packages listing, one per line, and read it from your bash script, you can do `brew install $(cat my-file-with-dependencies)`.

Suppose you have in `brewfile-basic`:

```
hub
git-extras
bash-completion
```

Now create `brewbundle.sh`:

```
brew install $(cat brewfile-basic)

# Cleaning up Brew caches

brew linkapps
brew cleanup
brew prune
```

You haven't run this command for a while. For the last months, it was said it was deprecated.